# How can my title be centered without "padding-cheat"?

Tags: html, css

How can I center my `h1` tag into the `middle` of my `banner` without setting a `padding`?

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="bannerContainer">
        <h1>Group Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.bannerContainer {
}
```

Can you do something with `vertical-align: middle;` and `display: table-cell;` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `transform`, you can position in centrally like so: http://jsfiddle.net/otghf6zo/1/

adding this code will position the title in the exact middle of the containing div regardless of size.

```
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: But how can I display it in the `center center`?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/otghf6zo/1/   I have added `position: relative;` to the container and removed the defualt `margin` that is applied to `<h1>`

Comment: Thanks, really helped me. @SamWillis

Answer (score 2):

There's several options, I recommend looking through this - https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

One option would be: http://jsfiddle.net/dtq7fed3/  which uses a line-height on the container that is the same of the height of the banner.

```
.banner {
   height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
}
.bannerContainer {
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 500px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

This only works if the banner height is going to remain stagnant

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS table** like this

```css
.banner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bannerContainer {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="bannerContainer">
        <h1>Group Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or **Flexbox** like this

```css
.banner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="bannerContainer">
        <h1>Group Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```